# Add Member in List mailchimp api not working [list memeber] cURL: The API key provided is linked to a different datacenter (status:403)

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Mailchimp list add member using API Not working
Request:

```
      $apikey = '#####################-us15';
        $data = array(
            'email_address' => 'test+mailchimp@gmail.com',
            'status' => 'subscribed',
            'merge_fields' => array(
                'FNAME' => 'taiabur rahman'
            )
        );
        $json_data = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/6de91c2e1c/members/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("content-type: application/json"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "apikey:" . $apikey);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);

    $response_string = curl_exec($ch);
    $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    $curl_errno = curl_errno($ch);
    $curl_error = curl_error($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($response_string);

    die('Mailchimp executed');
```

Response:
    {    "type":"http://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/error-glossary/",
           "title":"Wrong Datacenter",
           "status":403,
           "detail":"The API key provided is linked to a different datacenter",
           "instance":""
    }

Answer (score 2):

Hi Change the url to https://us15.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/ on mailchimp documentation

> if the last part of your MailChimp API key is us6, all API endpoints
>   for your account are available at https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/.

you can read the full documentation [here](https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/guides/get-started-with-mailchimp-api-3/)